# How to use Django's PASSWORD_HASHERS with custom model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I am creating authentication model for my project, I want to use Django's PASSWORD_HASHERS for password field in my model, can you suggest me the proper way?

My model.py file

```
class vendor_registration(models.Model):
    first_name  = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    email_id = models.EmailField(max_length=70,blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
```

I know how to use it for the User model, But need solution for custom user model.Thanks

Comment: Please tell me you're not really storing passwords in raw text. Your user model should inherit from django's base model

Comment: Don't try to write your own authentication model like this. The safe way is to define a [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model). If you subclass `AbstractUser` or `AbstractBaseUser`, then Django will take care of the password field for you.

Answer (score 0):

Although you should subclass `AbstractBaseUser` for your custom user but if you really wanna go without it then here it is how to do it.

You can use [make_password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.make_password) function in your save method:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

class vendor_registration(models.Model):
        first_name  = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
        email_id = models.EmailField(max_length=70,blank=False)
        password = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
        created_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
                self.password = make_password(self.password)
        super(vendor_registration, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This will only hash the password when a user is created, you should also consider whenever your user is updated.

Comment: sorry I am at entry level for django, should I write this fun instead of password = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True) will it take password field in query and create hasher of it before storing in database?Do I need to add password_hasher in setting.py?

Comment: I have updated my answer and  no need to add password_hashers

Comment: still if I run the query in shell user_registration_data = vendor_registration.objects.create(first_name='Piyush',last_name='Wanare',password='@W454rtdQ',email_id='nw@gmail.com',created_at=datetime.datetime.now())  and checked in database showing same password as I given in input.

Comment: AbstractBaseUser sounds interesting can you tell me how should be the model and query for it so that it will automatically store hash value of the password instead of passing hash value to the query?